# Render LocalReport from Reportviewer in Black and White PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, reportviewer, localreport

This is how I export my report from ReportViewer in PDF:

```
Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamids;
string mimeType;
string encoding;
string extension;
byte[] myBytes;
string reportName = hfReportName.Value;

myBytes = rvReport.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);

Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();  
Response.ContentType = mimeType;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + reportName + "_" + ddlPracGroup.SelectedItem + "." + extension);
Response.BinaryWrite(myBytes);
Response.Flush();
```

Is it any way to export this report in `Black and White` Only?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will post my solution in case if somebody will have this questions.

I add one more parameter in rdlc report `IsPrintType`. This is boolean parameter. In SSRS you can set report to be black and white only. When you click your print button, `reload report with this parameter > print report using code above > reload report back with color`

If need code sample, just let me know

Comment: How do you set the report to black and white? Where do you set IsPrintType?